# Batch File Copy "Syntax is Incorrect"

Tags: batch-file

So i've done a lot of Batch file stuff, but this is confusing me.

I have `"copy test.txt C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos"`
in my batch file, and it returns "The syntax of the command is incorrect". Im copying the txt file from my flash drive onto my computer so im trying to keep the current directory of the flash drive, then obviously put it into my test folder.

I feel like this should be simple but I am so confused as to why its not working.

Comment: You do not have the quotes in your batch file, right? Anyway, put quotes around each path, like: `copy "test.txt" "C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos"` (the _space_ is causing trouble otherwise)

Comment: @aschipl that did it, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would do this as the code:

```
copy "test.txt" "C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos"
```